# How do you disable animations at the system level for an android device/emulator using adb with API 23?

Tags: android, adb

Based on reading, the values `window_animation_scale`, `transition_animation_scale` and `animator_duration_scale` need to be set to 0

The following works for API 22 but not for API 23:

```
adb shell settings put global window_animation_scale 0.0
```

Even the below command did not work for API 23

```
adb shell content update --uri content://settings/system --bind value:s:0.0 --where 'name="window_animation_scale"'
```

We want to disable animations to prevent flaky visual test failures only. 
We do not want to introduce this logic in the application and hence want to apply it at the system level rather than through the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The adb shell settings commands are good enough. It is just that you have to do a clean reboot for these settings to come into effect.

The key to the solution is to do a clean reboot after you have changed the settings. `sudo reboot` is what you have to avoid and embrace
`$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb shell “su 0 am start -a android.intent.action.REBOOT”`

I have also written a [blog](https://medium.com/@sagarmaurya/are-android-animations-annoying-you-989b960a3b13) on the same issue.

Comment: Why do you need to restart? If we just run `adb shell settings put global ...` we can immediately observe the result. That command behaves the same as going to device settings and doing it with taps. Tried on API 24 emulator.

Comment: I can't comment on the "why", but the settings appear to be correct after restart. What is `su 0 am start ...`?

Comment: Echoing others - just tried these 2 commands for settings from the console on a userdebug build and the results were instant - all transition animations were disabled. Android 10 in use.

Answer (score 40):

You can execute the following adb commands to disable the animations:

```
adb shell settings put global window_animation_scale 0
adb shell settings put global transition_animation_scale 0
adb shell settings put global animator_duration_scale 0
```

Also, you could take a look at this [repo](https://github.com/finn-no/android_emulator_hacks)

Build the project and download the generated .apk file and follow the instructions mentioned in that project to disable the animations and you should have a smooth sailing afterwards. You could also download the same .apk file from a lot of other sources (go google!).

Once you have the .apk file then issue the following commands:

```
 adb install -r android_emulator_hacks.apk
 adb shell pm grant no.finn.android_emulator_hacks android.permission.SET_ANIMATION_SCALE
 adb shell am start -n no.finn.android_emulator_hacks/no.finn.android_emulator_hacks.HackActivity
```

Answer (score 9):

The answer by Mark W should be accepted
You can also save it as a shell script for convenience, i.e.:

```
#!/bin/sh
adb shell settings put global window_animation_scale 0.0
adb shell settings put global transition_animation_scale 0.0
adb shell settings put global animator_duration_scale 0.0
```

then in terminal just call

```
sh path/to/file.sh
```

Or go one step further and save an alias shortcut in your bash profile :)

Answer (score -2):

Check this Bash Script

```
 adb shell update global set value='0.0' where name='window_animation_scale'
 adb shell update global set value='0.0' where name='transition_animation_scale'
 adb shell update global set value='0.0' where name='animator_duration_scale'
```

Hope it helps